# Inconsistencies between SAML and OIDC in Firebase Auth Signin

Tags: firebase-authentication, openid, saml, google-cloud-identity

**Base Scenario**
There is a user in Firebase Auth with userID `1234` and email `user@email.com` with an additional facebook provider linked.

**Signing in with an OpenID Connect Provider**

1. Create an OpenIDConnect Provider within Google Cloud Platform's Identity Platform
2. Use the newly created provider to sign in with the email `user@email.com`

**Result**: You'll get an `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` error with the credentials sent back. This is the expected behavior.

However:

**Signing in with an SAML Provider**

1. Create an SAML Provider within Google Cloud Platform's Identity Platform
2. Use the newly created provider to sign in with the email `user@email.com`

**Result**: The SAML provider is automatically linked to the original firebase user with the userID still `1234`. However, it also replaces the previously set Facebook Provider.

Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong?  The real issue is the replacing of the providerID, but the inconsistencies seem troubling.

-- UPDATE --

Authentication is performed for both OIDC and SAML similar to these docs:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-oidc

Specifically:

```
  let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider(providerID);
  this.firebaseApp.auth().
    signInWithPopup(provider)
```

where `providerID` is either `saml.someprovider` or `oidc.someprovider`

Comment: The OIDC scenario should behave similar to SAML and NOT produce an error. Are you using one of the `linkWith..` methods in OIDC scenario? Please update your question with details on your OIDC flow.

Comment: @identigral  Yeah, that would make the most sense to me, however without it replacing the already linked providers. I've added an update that specifically shows the code.

Comment: The email of the SAML signed in user must be considered verified, whereas the email is the OIDC sign-in flow is not. Can you check the `emailVerified` field on the SAML signed in user to confirm this?

Comment: @bojeil You are brilliant and correct!  SAML email is considered verified, and OIDC is not (a bit strange since they are both coming from the same provider in this case). Now at least I understand the discrepancy and why it's happening, but I'll still need a way to deal with the fact that a verified email address will fully replace providers. Thank you very much for your help and insight!

Comment: @bojeil It's now essentially this issue, which I believe you commented on, and was reported, but the issue never seems fully resolved https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1180